# must implement title when canShowCallout is YES

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm getting this exception when trying to show the callout on my map annotation, even if the title is set.

This is the init method I'm using in my MapAnnotation class:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl subtitle:(NSString *)sub andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    titles = ttl;
    coordinate = c2d;
    subtitle = sub;
    return self;
}
```

Then, somewhere in another class I'm creating the annotations (2 in two different methods):

```
MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:[formatter stringFromDate:sourceDate] subtitle:@"test" andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

And this is the annotations method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
        return nil;

    static NSString *s = @"ann";
    MKAnnotationView *pin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:s];
    if (!pin) {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:s];
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
        pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
        pin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }
    return pin;
}
```

Another thing I'd like to do is use two different images for the two map annotations.
Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Daij-Djan the one in the question's title.

Comment: there is no error message or anything

Comment: if the title is your error message, then the meaning seems clear enough :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you MapAnnotation should contain title property, not titles for map callout to work. Declare it as follows

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
```

Comment: pin is a MKAnnotationView object, there's no title property for it.

Comment: my MapAnnotation does contain a title property.

Comment: No, it is named as titles not title as you have posted in your question above.

Comment: Look at your MapAnnotation's initWithTitle method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43821/discussion-between-ldindu-and-aleph72)

Comment: @Idindu: declared the same, it is unused. Still crash is there.